# How to move a folder of a repository to another repository of different Organization

Tags: git, github, repository, move, organization

How to move a folder in a GitHub repo of a organization to a different folder in different repo of another organization.

So just folder movement from on repo to another repo between different organizations (in main/customized branch).

Can we do it via GUI only?

I tried via Git bash and it is possible to do with commands. But for the sake of quick transfer via user interface, I wanted to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, there is no way of doing this through GUI but you can do this by manually copying and pasting.

Steps:

1. create a new folder in your desired place
2. open both repositories source and destination in two tabs
3. copy the desired files from the folder from the source repo.
4. paste the copies files in the desired folder in the destination